# How to close keyboard when user opens the drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, drawer

I am using `flutter_zoom_drawer`, i want when user opens the drawer on slide, not clicking on drawer icon, i want to dismiss the keyboard. my drawer code is on another screen and texfield is on another screen.

here is my zoom drawer code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ZoomDrawer(
      controller: _drawerController,
      // disableDragGesture: true,
      mainScreenScale: 0.2,
      style: DrawerStyle.defaultStyle,
    
      menuScreen: MenuPage(),
      mainScreen: BottonBarNavigation(selectedIndex:widget.index),
      borderRadius: 27.0,
      slideWidth: ScreenSize.widthSize * 0.78,
      showShadow: false,
      angle: 0.0,
      shadowLayer1Color: Colors.red,
    
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: AppColors.blueBgColor.withOpacity(0.3),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 8,
        ),
      ],
      menuBackgroundColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
      // mainScreenOverlayColor: Colors.amber,
      openCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      closeCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
    );
  }
```

there is only option of `disableDragGesture` property but not and function. Please help to do this.

Comment: wherever you put the slide code just put this code on top of it. => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

Comment: is there any callback that tells you that drawer is getting open or opened. than just put the FocusSc....  line from the above comment

Comment: @TusharPatel i didn't put any slide code

Comment: @pixel there is no callback function i get, can you look ```https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zoom_drawer``` this link and see if there's any callback function

Comment: you can listen changes on controllers statenotifier I guess

Answer (score 1):

Before you call open drawer function you can call.

```
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    /*youre code here*/
```